# Get Sprite's position in another class

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

This is probably a dumb question ,but here is my situation.

I have an `SKShapeNode` rect that goes from left to right on the screen as follows :

```
      // GameScene.swift

  var rect = SKShapeNode()
  var counter = 0{

    didSet{  
        rect.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(counter) , y: frame.midY)

        if CGFloat(counter) > frame.width{
            counter = 0
      }}}


override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    counter =       counter + 4     
}
```

In the ViewController.swift I try to get the `rect.position` like this , which I know is wrong because it creates a new Instance.

```
//ViewController.swift

 let gameScene = GameScene()

@IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {

//        gameScene.rect.position = games.frame.CGPoint(x: 200, y: 400)
          print(gameScene.rect.position)         // Always returns (0,0)

}
```

**Question:** How can I get `rect.position` in real time from the other class. So that whenever I press the button , I get the actual position of the `rect`?

**UPDATE**

On Ron's suggestion I updated the `viewDidLoad` method in my `ViewController.swift` ***from*** this :

```
 let gameScene = GameScene()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    if let view = self.spriteView {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {

            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)
              }}
```

***to***  this :

```
   var gameScene : GameScene!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let view = self.spriteView {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {    // SKScene changed to GameScene

            self.gameScene = scene                           // scene assigned to gameScene variable

            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)
        }
    }
```

**INTENTION**
I wanted to get the position of the  moving bar when the  `play` button was clicked. 
Note that the `GameScene` only represents a part of the actual screen

[image]

Comment: `print(gameScene.rect.position)` looks right. I suspect you get it right but it actually _is_ `(0,0)`

Comment: @shallowThought the instance of gameScene he is using is a different one than the one that the object is moving around in. It will always be 0,0 because it is a new blank instance of GameScene

Comment: @RonMyschuk I thought so too, but as `gameScene` is a constant, it should be impossible to re-initialize it somewhere else.

Comment: part of the problem here is that we don't know if it is a constant. it is shown out of context, and he isn't showing us how he instantiates his gameScene. it may be a constant, but he also may never be assigning his gameScene instance to that variable

Comment: @RonMyschuk I thought the `let gameScene =...`

Comment: @shallowThought  actually I just realized that he cannot assign the instance of gameScene to that variable because it is a "let". So yes while that is a constant variable it is not the variable that he needs. Judging from the fact the we haven't had any feedback from the OP I guess we care about this more than he does ;)

Comment: hha .. That's not entirely true , I fell asleep shortly after posting the question.
I updated my question as per  your suggestion in the answer.

Comment: Ah, sleep...the mortal enemy of the programmer. glad it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first transition to your GameScene (Assuming that you are going directly from your GameViewController to your GameScene) create a class level variable for gameScene. Then when you need the information from GameScene use that same variable vs. creating a new GameScene variable

```
var gameScene: GameScene!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {

        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'
        if let gameScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")  {
            self.gameScene = gameScene
            gameScene = .aspectFill
            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(gameScene)
        }
    }
}

func getCoords() {
    print("gameScene.rect.position \(gameScene.rect.position)")
}
```